# Difference name in list and any(name in s for s in list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and looked up how to find out, if something is inside a list and found

```
if any(name in s for s in list):
```

Later I found

```
if name in list:
```

which seems way more simple.
Why was the first option being suggested, what is the difference?

Comment: Well, neither are examples of *good* code, because they use `list` as a variable name.  The two are doing different things, the first, is checking if `name` is contained within an element of `list`, while the second is checking if `name` *is* an element of `list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't actually do the same thing.  Simple example to show the logical difference:

```
>>> list_ = ['spam', 'spam and eggs']
>>> name = 'eggs'
>>> any(name in s for s in list_)
True
>>> name in list_
False
```